# Android - why would Dialog not close upon dialog.dismiss()

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a bit of a strange problem.  When an activity starts, I show a dialog saying that some items are loading like this:

```
Dialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.topic_edit);

    dialog = new Dialog (this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.please_wait);
    dialog.setTitle("Loading The Comment.");

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.please_wait_text);
    text.setText("Please wait while the comment loads...");
    dialog.show();
```

I declare Dialog dialog right before the class declaration, and then whenever I try to dismiss it with `dialog.dismiss();` it doesn't close.

Here is the please_wait.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/please_wait_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Would someone know why the dialog does not close on `dialog.dismiss()`... I try the dismiss in an async call after the call returns. But I did check, and the line `dialog.dismiss()` is executed, just for some reason does not close the dialog.

This is how I try to dismiss the dialog:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: put your code where you put dialog.dismiss

Comment: "declare Dialog dialog right before the class declaration"??

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to dismiss it?  Also, as a side note, you may want to looking into the AlertDialog.Builder class for these types of simple dialogs, it will let you set a title and message as well as configure a few other options, without having to make a separate xml file for the layout.

Comment: For declaration of Dialog I meant just something like this:  Dialog dialog;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  ...so I mis-wrote, it is inside the class declaration :)

Comment: @Samir Mangroliya I just added how I try to dismiss the dialog in my original question

Comment: @Genadinik put `System.out.println("on post");` in `onPostExecute method`

Comment: show how you declare `dialog` variable. We need to see the scope, and this "declare Dialog dialog right before the class declaration" makes it quite suspicious

Comment: @SamirMangroliya He said that the line executes but doesn't dismiss.  Genadinik, there's still not really enough to go on here.  Can you post where you declare the dialog, the entirety of the method you set it up in, and more of the AsyncTask?  The code snippits you added look like they should work, so more context is needed.

Comment: Just posted the Dialog declaration and the beginning of the onCreate where I display the dialog.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure that when you are executing dialog.dismiss that it is pointing to the dialog you created. You have dialog as a class variable and there is a high chance it was assigned another dialog by the time of dismissal come. I had this one and turned out that dialog variable at dismiss time was no longer pointing to my actually dialog.

Putting a break point and seeing if the dialog variable upon creation/execution is still the same will probably help

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
```

according to the documentation it should be the right way to declare a Dialog.