# ProgressDialog remains open after doinbackground in asynctask in android

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have made an activity in that i am binding data from webservice to ListView by using custom adapter,I want to refresh that data when i click on reply button the "doReply" api will be called.All is going well but my progressDialog remains open after the ListView is loading,and can anyone also tell me how to refresh the list view ..my code is below:
**main.java**

```
public class ChatHistoryActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONArray msgArry;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    private ChatAdapter chatContent;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> msgList;
    ListView lv;
    JSONArray msgs = null;
    String pro_id, pro_name, pro_img, grup_id, sender_id, cust_id;
    TextView tv_switch;
    public boolean flag = false;
    Header header;
    Menu menu;
    Intent in;
    Button reply;
    RelativeLayout rl_reply;
    EditText et_reply;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_history);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        tv_switch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_switch);
        header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.header_msg);
        menu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.menu_msg);
        reply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reply);
        rl_reply = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_reply);
        rl_reply.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_reply = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_reply);
        menu.setSelectedTab(3);
        header.title.setText("Conversation");
        msgList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        pro_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
        sender_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
        grup_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_GROUP_ID);
        cust_id = Pref.getValue(ChatHistoryActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "");

        new GetChatHistory().execute();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                rl_reply.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        });
        // message reply ...!!Chat api(conversation)
        reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DoReply().execute();
                // new GetChatHistory().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new GetChatHistory().execute();
    }

    private class GetChatHistory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatHistoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            String query = Const.API_CHAT_HISTORY;
            url = "?customer_id=" + cust_id + "&group_id=" + grup_id + "&sender_id=" + sender_id + "&product_id=" + pro_id;
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            url = query + url;
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::My MESSGES URL::::::::::::::" + url);

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    msgArry = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    if (msgArry != null && msgArry.length() != 0) {
                        // looping through All Contacts

                        System.out.println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::" + msgArry.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < msgArry.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = msgArry.getJSONObject(i);

                            String custID = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
                            String custName = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME);
                            String proID = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                            String email = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_EMAIL);
                            String photo = Const.API_HOST + "/" + c.getString(Const.TAG_PHOTO);
                            String msg_body = c.getString(Const.TAG_MESSAGE_BODY);
                            HashMap<String, String> message = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID, custID);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME, custName);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, proID);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_EMAIL, email);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_PHOTO, photo);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_MESSAGE_BODY, msg_body);

                            msgList.add(message);

                        }
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "No messgaes found", "yehki", "Ok");
                                msgList.clear();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            chatContent = new ChatAdapter(ChatHistoryActivity.this, msgList);
            chatContent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(chatContent);

        }
    }

    /*
     * GET CONVERSATION LIST.........REPLY
     */
    private class DoReply extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatHistoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            String query = Const.API_MESSAGE_REPLY;
            url = "?customer_id=" + cust_id + "&group_id=" + grup_id + "&receiver_id=" + sender_id + "&product_id=" + pro_id + "&message=" + et_reply.getText().toString().trim();
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            url = query + url;
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::My MESSGES URL::::::::::::::" + url);

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    if (jsonObj.getString("status").equals("sucess")) {
                        et_reply.setText("");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "Message has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        et_reply.setText("");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "Message has not been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            chatContent = new ChatAdapter(ChatHistoryActivity.this, msgList);
            chatContent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(chatContent);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: instead of checking `pDialog.isShowing()` check whether pDialog is null..

Comment: are you sure onPostExecute() is being called???

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425963/android-why-would-dialog-not-close-upon-dialog-dismiss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your `onCreate()` and `onResume()` fire up an async task that set up a progress dialog, overwriting the `pDialog` variable in the activity. The dialog that gets dismissed is not necessarily the one that is being displayed.

- Only fire up the async task once.
- Store the progress dialog reference as a member in the async task object instead of activity so it does not get overwritten by someone else.

Comment: i am getting your point but i want to refresh my ListView data ,so that i have called in in onResume()

Comment: Then remove the call from `onCreate()`. `onResume()` gets called after `onCreate()` anyway.